# How to create Folder type (IPM.Contact) using MAPI in MFC/C++?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

I am created folder using MAPI API:

```
LPIMAPIFOLDER folder = NULL;

folder->CreateFolder(
ULONG ulFolderType, // here three type of folder type used
LPTSTR lpszFolderName,
LPTSTR lpszFolderComment, 
LPCIID lpInterface,
ULONG ulFlags,
LPMAPIFOLDER FAR * lppFolder
);
```

Here, three type of folder type used ...

1. `#define FOLDER_ROOT            ((ULONG) 0x00000000)`
2. `#define FOLDER_GENERIC         ((ULONG) 0x00000001)`
3. `#define FOLDER_SEARCH          ((ULONG) 0x00000002)`

Then, How create folder (type = **IPM.Contact**) using MAPI API ?